# AnimationController: Can we pass the TickerProvider vsync to an other class?

Tags: animation, flutter, ticker

I develop an application in Flutter with a lot of animations quite varied. I would like to structure my code by separating views, logic (model BLoC) and ANIMATIONS. For this problem I try to declare several times the same animation for buttons in a different class of my StatefulWidget.

However, I am stuck because I have to pass a TickerProvider to my animation class, and I do not do it the right way.

**Constructor animation class**

```
AppBloc(TickerProvider tickerProvider) {
    banimationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: tickerProvider,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      lowerBound: 0,
      upperBound: 0.05,
    );
}
```

**Declaration**

```
AppBloc(this);
```

I know this is probably not the right way, I wrote this code to illustrate my problem.

I just want to separate my animations declarations in an other file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TickerProvider** is a mixin. You can use multiple mixins in a class using **with** keyword. The best way to use the mixin uff **TickerProvider** is using it with **with** keyword.

**Example :**

```
  class _HomeState extends State<Home> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> _animation;
  AnimationController _animationController;

  GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn;
  GoogleSignInAccount _googleSignInAccount;
  GoogleSignInAuthentication _googleSignInAuthentication;
  FirebaseAuth _auth;

 // FacebookLoginResult _facebookLoginResult;
  // FacebookLogin _facebookLogin;
   // FirebaseUser facebookUser;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: 4));
    _animation = Tween<double>(begin: -1.0, end: 0.0).animate(CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn));

    _animationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return widget();
}
}
```

If you use the TickelProvider in this way then you can simply pass **this** as the value for the vsync.

Comment: Ok I used TickerProviderStateMixin upside down .. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `TickerProvider` is not a mixin. It is an interface that `TickerProviderStateMixin` implements. So instead this mixin is a `TickerProvider` but not the other way around.